How can I solve my error involving JDBC when I try to login?
I am trying to implement the login functionality as follows:
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="j" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<t:generalTemplate pageTitle="Login">
    <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>

    <j:if test="${message}!= null">
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            ${message}
        </div>
    </j:if>
    <form action="j_security_check" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="j_username" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="j_password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Register">Register here</a></p>
</t:generalTemplate>

I am using IntelliJ 2024, Glassfish 7 and MySQL on MacOS.
And I get this error:
[2024-05-11T21:34:08.222382+03:00] [GF 7.0.14] [WARNING] [] [com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WEB9102: Web Login Failed
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Failed jdbc login for 123.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:200)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:129)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:774)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.processSecurityCheck(AuthenticatorBase.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:504)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:186)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:425)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Failed jdbc login for 123.
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.authentication.glassfish.jdbc.JDBCLoginModule.authenticateUser(JDBCLoginModule.java:53)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.BasePasswordLoginModule.login(BasePasswordLoginModule.java:110)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:754)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:678)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:676)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:676)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:322)
    ... 31 more
]]

